# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] path not work,hence create error

Tags: php

I am using document root to provide absolute path which is not working. 
if i `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`  this path turns out to be `C:/wamp/www/`

it shows error

```
Warning: include_once(C:/wamp/www//library/includes/header.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\Library Lending management\library\library\book_search_comit.php on line 16
```

when i put full like `C:\wamp\www\Library Lending management\library\includes\header.php` it work fine.

what i find `"/"` creates problem when i use `"\"` it work fine.my problem is i  have lot of files which use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` which show dir path with `"/"` but i need `"\"`.
how can i make script workable.

Comment: how can i do please help me out...

Comment: Is that on your local system?I guess so by your paths

Comment: ya sir it on localhost i am building library management system

Comment: Library Lending management is missing from your include_once(C:/wamp/www//library/includes/header.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp...

Comment: @AnkurSaxena you have still problem, first delete space between Library Lending management, never give space. & yes above comment was write of techie_28.

Comment: Duplicate Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934563/php-include-once-is-not-working/14934665#14934665

Comment: @ techie_28 :-sir it's not the problem i use whole phat,this is not the problem...

Comment: @ Advait Amin:-i had asked that question,but on solving error i find it's "/" creates problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is defined in your server configuration so you can change it there.

A more robust way in my opinion is to define the root of your application using **dirname( _*FILE*_ )**. This will make your app more independent of configurations and be more "plug-and-play" which seems to suit a library collection.

I also encourage you to use the constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR instead of hard coding `"\"` or `"/"` in internal paths as this is more portable across platforms.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer

Comment: Yes, sorry, updated my answer. Forgot how $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] was set.

Comment: few extend you are correct but it give presents file location and i need one step back

Comment: You can get the level above by wrapping it in another `dirname()`, eg. `dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) )`.

Answer (score 0):

use str_replace() to change the path separator:

```
$docroot = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
include_once($docroot.'header.php'); // etc.
```

You may need another DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, depending on what $docroot ends up being.

Comment: okey i agree but i have to change in every page there 70-80 files,i think i  have to change each files...

Answer (score 0):

i use `dirname(dirname(__FILE__))` it work for me. `dirname(__FILE__)` give present location of file and `dirname(dirname(__FILE__))` give one step back dir.