# require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/defines.php'; not working

Tags: php, doctype, require-once

Is it possible to use `require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/defines.php';` I keep getting an error on it.

I tried
`require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'htdocs/comments3/defines.php');` 
 but it still won't work please help me.

im trying to recreate the project of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_fJoLdbVyM&list=PLyKBLKYqadGlmL6QLKCicUp9tQsybUII5
its a comment box using ajax[Javascript jQuery JSON PHP mysql]
but on episode 6 i cant follow it coz it starts erroring out for the darn defines.php
im using C:\xampp\htdocs\comments for my files path

Comment: you can use whatever you want, as long as the path/file you're building actually exists. Since it doesn't work for you, that path doesn't exist.

Comment: Please provide error detail also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974171/serverdocument-root-path-not-work-hence-create-error?rq=1

Comment: why don't you echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and check the path.

Comment: when i view my doc this is what i get
Warning: require_once(C:/xampp/htdocs/ so /htdocs/comments3/defines.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\comment3\index.php on line 1

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/ so /htdocs/comments3/defines.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\comment3\index.php on line 1

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me

```
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/myapp/defines.php');
```

where myapp is my applications name. So in case it will be

```
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/comments3/defines.php');
```

$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] points to `C:\Xampp\htdocs` on windows and similarly on other OS. so you need to give path from there starting with `/` so `/comments3/defines.php` and so on.

In case above does not work please share complete path of defines.php

In your case it is a spelling mistake at `comments3` instead of `comment3`

Comment: In that case above will work for you ie `require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/comments3/defines.php');`.

Comment: tried it still giving me
Warning: require_once(C:/xampp/htdocs/comments3/defines.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\comment3\index.php on line 1

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/comments3/defines.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\comment3\index.php on line 1


i dont get this error im not a pro at this please help many thanx for helping i really dont understand this

Comment: your folder name is comment `s `3 or comment3. because I see comments3 in required and comment3 as index.php location

Comment: ow man it worked dude you the best do you have contact email or facebook or skype when i get any more problems please id like your help

Comment: I am rarely available on my mail/fb/skype still you can mail me at `me[at]techphernalia[dot]com` and please mark it as answer.

Comment: im getting another error similar to the one i had earlier but this tym its with include this is my code ?php require_once INCLUDES . '/comment3/includes/comment_box.php'; ?

Comment: i tried using same changes i did earlier as you shown me but im getting the error for
Warning: require_once(C:/xampp/htdocs/comments3/defines.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\comment3\index.php on line 1

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/comments3/defines.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\comment3\index.php on line 1

did u say http://home.techphernalia.com/??? or is this tweeter?

Comment: sir if i was to upload this to a  web host do i jus change the codes to /defines.php??

Comment: No it is fine and it will work as you are not hard coding any url. You are just playing safe. :) `me@techphernalia.com` is my email id. Please mark the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: sir i sent u an email did u recieve it yet?

Comment: replied. You can get help accordingly. Please mark the answer.

Comment: @Durgesh Chaudhary : I am facing same problem . My working directory is 'httpdocs/index.php' and I want to enter 'httpdocs/login/include/config.php' , I am trying with `require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/login/include/config.php'); `  but it is not working .What is the exact code?

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
<?php require_once ('defines.php');  ?>
```